# Create a new view with swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am new with iOS an in this website. I was using a navigation controller and `pushViewController` to switch to other views. But now I am trying to push to a view without a navigation bar. The new view should contain a Done button which once clicked should bring the user back to the last view. Do you have an idea how to achieve that? I tried this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main.Storyboard", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FormViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I got an error

`'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle.` I get the same error if I try `FormViewController` as the story board name. I set `FormViewController` as Storyboard ID and also as the swift file name I want to use with the interface, and `Main.Storyboard` is the name of the storyboard file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the `storyboard` and accessing `ViewController`, you will have to follow these steps:

**1. Assign Storyboard ID to ViewController**

In your `Storyboard`, select the desired `ViewController` and assign **Storyboard Id** to it

[image]

**2. Access the ViewController**

To access the `ViewController`, you will need the **Storyboard Id** which we have set in the first step.

If you have only one `storyboard` you can simply do like this

```
let controller = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerID")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**

### OR

**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerID")
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are using **multiple storyboards** within the same project then you will have to access `storyboard` with it's name **(without its extension i.e .Storyboard)**:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerID")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't add the ".storyboard" part of the filename, it does that automatically:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```